# I am trying to implement expandablelistview in my test app but the app crashes everytime

Tags: android, crash, expandablelistview

This is the part of Logcat : 
It says that its caused by
MainActivity.java:41)
I checked the ids and they are done the same way as in the tutorial.

```
.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread
```

This is main activity.java
    package com.appt.shreyabisht.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
HashMap <String, List<String>> Services_category;
List<String> Services_list;
ExpandableListView Exp_list;
services_adapter adapter;



Button btn_sign;
Button btn_sign_up;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign);
    btn_sign.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_sign_up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);
    btn_sign_up.setOnClickListener(this);
    Exp_list=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    Services_category = Dataprovider.getinfo();
    Services_list = new ArrayList<String>(Services_category.keySet());
    adapter = new services_adapter(this, Services_category, Services_list);
    Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void btclick() {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.appt.shreyabisht.second"));
}

private void btsignclick() {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.appt.shreyabisht.third"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign:
            btclick();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_sign_up:
            btsignclick();
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appt.shreyabisht.test" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.second"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.second" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.third"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.third" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.after_signin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_after_signin" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.after_signin" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

after_signup.xml ( This page has expandable list)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.after_signin"
android:background="@drawable/download">

<TextView android:text="@string/welcome_header" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFDD76"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView5" />


<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/exp_list"
    android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:divider="#A4C739"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5" />
```

parent file (expand_1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:id="@+id/parent_id"
    android:textColor="#A4C739"/>
```

child file (child.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

services_adapter.java

```
package com.appt.shreyabisht.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
```

/**
 * Created by SHREYA BISHT on 11/19/2014.
 */
public class services_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context ctx;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> Services_category;
private List<String> Services_list;

public services_adapter(Context ctx, HashMap<String, List<String>> Services_category, List<String> Services_list)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.Services_category = Services_category;
    this.Services_list = Services_list;

}
@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return Services_list.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
    return Services_category.get(Services_list.get(arg0)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return Services_list.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
    return Services_category.get(Services_list.get(parent)).get(child);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
    return child;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int parent , boolean isExpanded, View convertview, ViewGroup parentview) {
        String group_title = (String) getGroup(parent);
    if(convertview == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_1, parentview, false);

    }
    TextView parent_textview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.parent_id);
    parent_textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    parent_textview.setText(group_title);
    return convertview;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean lastchild, View convertview, ViewGroup parentview) {
    String child_title = (String) getChild(parent,child);
    if(convertview == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_child, parentview, false);
    }
    TextView child_textview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.child);
        child_textview.setText(child_title);

    return convertview;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int i) {

}

@Override
public long getCombinedChildId(long l, long l2) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getCombinedGroupId(long l) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

and the strings file
strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_name">test</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="enter_name">Username</string>
<string name="enter_username">Enter</string>
<string name="calling_activity_name">The username and password entered was</string>
<string name="sign_in">Sign In</string>
<string name="user_password">Password</string>
<string name="App_name">StayMax</string>
<string name="user_name">Username:</string>
<string name="details_header">Please provide login details</string>
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
<string name="title_activity_second">second</string>
<string name="title_activity_third">third</string>
<string name="confirm_password">Confirm Password</string>
<string name="enter_location">Enter Location</string>
<string name="sign_up">Sign Up</string>
<string name="sign_up_btn">Sign Up</string>
<string name="title_activity_after_signin">after_signin</string>
<string name="button_login">Log In</string>
<string name="welcome_header">Welcome to Ayaya</string>
```

logcat after making the suggested changes:

```
Process: com.appt.shreyabisht.test, PID: 942
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.appt.shreyabisht.test/com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 06:07:32.739      942-942/com.appt.shreyabisht.test I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 942 SIG: 9
```

When this is set:
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

The error i get is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

mainactivity.java:41 is :         Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);

When this is set: setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_signin);
The error I get is :

```
             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

MainActivity.java:34 is :      btn_sign.setOnClickListener(this);
which is for a button on another activity.

Comment: Please provide your logcat.

Comment: `following a tutorial`. You must have very good reasons not to provide a link.

Comment: @greenapps this is the tutorial

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_h94Kqyc-Ag&src_vid=BkazaAeeW1Q&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_1141555157

Comment: You should post your code again ofcourse. And mark line 41.

Comment: @greenapps deleted the code by mistake. I have uploaded all the files again. Please help me figure out the error. Thanks

Comment: I also have the dataprovider file in place and ive checked it. I believe that the error has got to do with exp_list but i cant figure out what to correct.

Comment: `MainActivity.java:41`. You still did not tell which line that is. Please tell to resolve the null pointer problem.

Comment: @greenapps I have updated the question with the answer.

Comment: Finally! `mainactivity.java:41 is : Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);`. (Please edit your post and tell that at the third line).  This tells Exp_list==null because findViewById could not find it as you used the wrong .xml file. So you took the right .xml file and now you have a different pointer which is null. Now  btn_sign is null as it is not defined in that .xml file. You are clearly mixing up buttons/views from two .xml files.

Comment: @greenapps indeed yes! btn_sign is on a diff xml and exp_list on a different one. btn_sign is for a button that lets me sign in. after that i reach to a page which has expandable view. How do i make it work?

Comment: @greenapps Suppose I set it to :   setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_signin) Now the content is set to the xml file that has the expandanble view. But now since the contentview is set to that xml file, it wont recognize btn_sign because it is on another xml? Am i correct? If yes, how do i solve this?

Comment: Ypu have two pages/activites apparently. So use the one for the one and the other for the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using activity_main to set content view

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Where is your activity_main.xml? Are you using right xml file?

I think you are refering to wrong xml file and your views are in another xml. please check.

Comment: Indeed. That will be it. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` should be `setContentView(R.layout.after_signup);`.

Comment: @greenapps  I made the suggested changes but it still doesnt work. I will add the logcat to the question

Comment: @kumarranjan, i made it :setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_signin);

Comment: do i need to declare child and parent activity in the manifest file?

Comment: Also, i would really appreciate it if someone could explain why i had to make the above changes. i have a main activity and then second activity which leads me to after_signin. which xml file should i put in this command and why?   thanks

Comment: you are getting this exception because your layout file is not containing the view you are refering ie. btn_sign. Its simple to understand, you can access any view in your activity only if it exists in your activity. To set a content ie. layout or views to activity you use setContentView. I guess it will help you to understand the concept.

Comment: @KumarRanjan thank you for your input. So how is it done? I have my content view set to after_signup.xml and i have a find view by id for a button thats in another xml. can i set contentview to both these files? :/

Comment: No, you can't...at a time you can set content view to only one layout.

Comment: i dont understand. To make this work, Ill have to ditch the btn_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign but then my button wont work. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Whats the design of your application? Do you have a screen with two buttons and an another screen with a expandable list view?

Comment: yes. imagine a first page which asks user to either sign in or sign up. Suppose the user wants to sign in, he will press the sign in button and will be redirected to a page where he can enter username and password and press a button "sign in" which directs him to the page with the expandable view.

Comment: For this case you need three different activity. Lets say activities A,B,C. Activty A will show two buttons hence it will use layout with two button and activity A will handle the click of these two buttons. Lets say user click button 1 ie. sign in button, it will start another activity B, which will use another layout with username, password and login button. On click of login button it will start activity C, which will contain your expandable view in content view. Hope now you get your answer.

Comment: Thats how ive made it so far.

Comment: Then why you want to refer the sign up button in activity with expandable list view? They should be on different activities, right? and in that case you can set content for both activities separately.

Comment: Thats how ive made it so far. page_first and its xml. another page for sign in and one for signup. I have now 2 activities and a main  activity . These two activities basically have textview, editview and a button in them. till now, I had the contentview set for activity_main. then i made another expandable page added that to the manifest file, edited mainactivity but it wont work because i have to change the contentview. I hope im making the situation clear.

Comment: yes. how do i set content for both activities separately, thats my question now.  In mainactivity i set it to the page with the expandable view and the other?

Comment: The code that you have shared have only one activity ie. MainActivity. Dude, I hope you understand the difference between activity class and layout xml..Please get your basic good first.

Comment: I do understand the difference between the layout xml and activity  but you are right, i dont know many things that i should know before building a test. I kind of grasp things as I go. I will try to ask better questions next time :)

Comment: btw you can accept it as answer if it solved your basic problem :)